# Start app on login

Tags: facebook, process, background

I'm trying to write a facebook app that WOULD (I don't even know if its possible yet) start running after the user login process. I mean, the user wouldn't have to access the app page to execute what I want to do, it would be like a background process that would be running for a limited amount of time after the login.

So, is that possible? I didn't find out this anywhere I've looked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just can give you a "maybe".

Your startpage will just contain the facebook sdk functions, to complete a login.
If login complete redirect to the rootpage of your application, then set a timer, to give access for a limited time. If timer ran out -> redirect to the login page.

Comment: I was thinking more of, maybe, a jquery script that would be monitoring what the user does at the login aftertime, but I could really use your idea, though, thanks anyway.